# Datashader on Google Colab - blank output

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, datashader

I'm trying out [Datashader](https://datashader.org/) on Google Colab to visualise a large dataset of longitudes and latitudes colored logarithmically with the `colorcet.fire` colormaps, but my code throws a completely blank output.

Code in text:

```
import datashader as ds
import pandas as pd
import colorcet

data = pd.read_csv('hab.csv', usecols=['longitude','latitude'])
cvs = ds.Canvas()
agg = cvs.points(data, 'latitude', 'longitude')
ds.tf.set_background(ds.tf.shade(agg, cmap=colorcet.fire, how='log'))
```

What I see on Colab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a collab user, but yes, when I run your code locally with the five datapoints shown I get a blank plot. In my local version, it's because the code is specifying a colormap whose highest value is white, and for a few scattered points each of them are at the highest value. The code uses `set_background`, perhaps trying to set the background to black as would be suitable for that colormap, but it doesn't specify "black" and so the `set_background` call does nothing. If I specify the background color and add Datashader spreading so that these single datapoints are easier to see, I do get a plot from your code:

[image: screenshot of sample code]

```
cvs = ds.Canvas()
agg = cvs.points(data, 'latitude', 'longitude')
ds.tf.set_background(ds.tf.shade(ds.tf.spread(agg, px=10), cmap=colorcet.fire, how='log'), "black")
```

[image]

You may have some other problem as well, though, since the plot you showed wasn't just white, it appeared to be transparent. And if your dataset is indeed large, you should see output anyway, because data points would then overlap and use all the colors in the colormap.